# Titanium ImageView Width attribute not working Android

Tags: android, android-layout, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have set width attribute of the imageView. But it is not taking up the width. It is not the aspect ratio thing. It is something else:

```
// Create an ImageView.
var content = Ti.UI.createView(
{
    width : '100%',
    height : '90%',
    bottom : '0%',
});

// Create an ImageView.
var dialerImage = Ti.UI.createImageView(
{
    image: '/images/dial.png',
    width : '98%',
    center : '51%'
});


content.add(dialerImage);
```

But the image never takes that width, it only takes somewhere near 60% of width. I have tried a lot of things. i.e: setting both width and height, setting height only, setting the width and/or height to Ti.UI.FILL, but to no avail.

Output with the above code: 
[image]

I am using **Nexus 4**. Please also note that if I edit the image and scale it, then it takes more width.

Comment: why are you using center and bottom.i think height and width would be enough

Comment: @Wahhab_mirza I have also tried removing center and bottom, still the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the imageView does not take `percentage` in `width` or `height` attributes. I'l have to give the width in dp.

Calculate width in dps from `Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth`

```
var widthDps = ( Math.ceil( 0.98 * Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth)) ;

// Create an ImageView.
var dialerImage = Ti.UI.createImageView(
{
    image: '/images/dial.png',
    width : widthDps,
    left: 4
});
```